# Computer Graphics - JOGL Texture mapping

Tags: java, jogl

I am trying to implement the earth model using JOGL.
But I am struggling mapping texturing so could anybody advice me or give me reference?

This is my code procedure.

1. Generate tessellated sphere with triangle.
2. mapping the earth on the sphere
   a. read image
   b. bind the image to the sphere  <--- here is what I cannot solve..

below is my pseudo code

```
public void init (GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
  //read textre
}

public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
  GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
  textureEarth.enable(gl);
  textureEarth.bind(gl)
  (do I need to do something else here?)

  // Render the Sphere
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gluSphere. Have you looked at the project jogl-demos on Github? Maybe it contains an interesting example. Try to see if the texture coordinates fit into your needs as is.

I advise you to look at [this example](http://java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jogl/sphere-mapping-quadrics-in-opengl-nehe-tutorial-jogl-2.html).

N.B: The questions about JOGL should be asked on [its official forum](http://forum.jogamp.org).

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer if it fits into your needs.